# docker build for multiple platform with different Dockerfiles

Tags: docker

I need to build a docker image for arm64 and amd64, and I've already used `buildx`.

But the build process for the two platform is lightly different and I would need to use two different Dockerfiles. How should I do?

The detail: the image use [s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) and it has two different tarballs depending on the arch

```
ADD https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/releases/download/v${S6_OVERLAY_VERSION}/s6-overlay-x86_64.tar.xz /tmp

ADD https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/releases/download/v${S6_OVERLAY_VERSION}/s6-overlay-aarch64.tar.xz /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create an image that the two dockerfiles can share and do a multi-stage build process. See [here in the docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-a-previous-stage-as-a-new-stage)

Answer (score 0):

solution: https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/issues/512#issuecomment-1421339335

```
ARG S6_OVERLAY_VERSION="v3.1.3.0"
RUN wget "https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/releases/download/${S6_OVERLAY_VERSION}/s6-overlay-noarch.tar.xz" -O "/tmp/s6-overlay-noarch.tar.xz" && \
    tar -C / -Jxpf "/tmp/s6-overlay-noarch.tar.xz" && \
    rm -f "/tmp/s6-overlay-noarch.tar.xz"
RUN [ "${TARGETARCH}" == "arm64" ] && FILE="s6-overlay-aarch64.tar.xz" || FILE="s6-overlay-x86_64.tar.xz"; \
    wget "https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/releases/download/${S6_OVERLAY_VERSION}/${FILE}" -O "/tmp/${FILE}" && \
    tar -C / -Jxpf "/tmp/${FILE}" && \
    rm -f "/tmp/${FILE}"
```